# How to repair Mac partitions without Internet Recovery and Rescue USB?

Tags: bootcamp, partition

Resizing the `C:\` drive under Windows(bootcamp) corrupted mac partitions. Neither Mac OS X nor Windows are able to boot. Holding the `Option(ALT)` key shows only Windows, which can't boot.

- Internet Recovery doesn't work giving -2002F error.
- No other Mac nearby to create recovery USB.
- I have only Windows PC with internet in my disposal to fix this.
- No single user nor verbose mode loads.

How do I recover the Mac partition table? I heard TestDisk could fix that, but how do I run it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy files on Mac that fails to boot?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136388/how-to-copy-files-on-mac-that-fails-to-boot)

Comment: You are asking the same question twice!

Comment: no, these are different macs with different problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows had changed the HD partition map from GUID Partition Table(GPD) to MBR. And made HD a "dynamic disk". This is why Mac Os wasn't able to boot.

So, I've tried 1001 ways to recover. Nothing worked. Interned Recovery gives -2002F error. Macbook pro 2012 can't boot from bootable DVD to use DiskWarrior, Drive Genius or similar. It can't boot from OS X Lion install DVD. I could boot Windows recovery console and tried TestDisk which failed to write something to HFS+. Also tried some Windows third party applications which also failed.

**I asked a friend with latest Mavericks(which I had too) to make a Recovery USB using [OS X Recovery Disk Assistant v1.0](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) and make a DMG file from it using Disk Utility and send me over internet. Then I used the [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) application under Windows and burned DMG on my USB stick. I was able to boot from this USB stick into Recovery Mode and from there I can reinstall Mac Os X Mavericks. Somehow it sees my Ethernet cable and doesn't give error.**

Note: that Disk Utility wasn't able to recover partitions. I tried to run DiskWarrior from terminal but it gave me an error. TestDisk didn't run too. I could recover or backup my files using [Paragon Rescue Kit for Mac Bootable CD](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-mac/), but there was no need since it's my new macbook and I didn't have much files there. I made a clean installation on a USB stick and run DiskWarrior and Drive Genius, none of them could fix partitions. So I gave up and reformatted HD.

That's probably not the answer on how to fix partitions, but that's how I solved this. If somebody finds a way to fix partitions please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do with a stock Mac to fix the hard drive.

You could plug the hard drive in another Mac (as a secondary drive, not a boot one) and see what Disk Utility tells you (press `command-space` then type `Disk Utility` to launch it) about it but it's not guaranteed to help you much. I am not even sure it can correctly repair a boot hard drive.

Your best bet is using a disk repair program such as DiskWarrior (http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/).

It costs a bit but has a very good reputation and saved many damaged hard drives. Cf http://daringfireball.net/2010/03/ode_to_diskwarrior_superduper_dropbox for a great example of it saving important data.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) (version 5, around 120$) can fix partition table damage and may possibly be able to fix this.